# muliple steps oledb operation generated using sql server compact edition

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, visual-c++, c++11

I am using SQL Server Compact Edition.
One of the column size of my table is more than 500.
When I am Selecting from this table I am getting this error in visual studio:

```
multiple steps oledb operation generated
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: I'm really not sure how related to C++ your question is.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when you pass an unexpected value in one of your DB operation (say you pass NULL to a non-NULL field for example).

I would expect the error message to be longer and more informative (did you truncate it ?). In the current situation, that's pretty much all we can say about it.

A quick google search gave me [that link](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-is-this-multiple-step-ole-db-error.html) which may help.